# How do I edit php.ini in a docker container?

Tags: 18.04, php, docker, wordpress, container

So I'm running the wordpress docker container and I want to increase the upload file size limit set in php.ini.  My problem is I can't find that file anywhere.

I installed the container with a docker-compose file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For development purpose you could just bind mount it from the host to the container take a look [here](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/)

To a production environment you could think to personalize the container by build your own on top of it.

For example in your docker-compose is declared the docker image of wordpress calleds [wordpress:5.4.0-php7.2-fpm-alpine](https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/blob/bf85cc7bf33afbbfadd86ba79b3d8ad325289057/php7.2/fpm-alpine/Dockerfile)

you can create your own Dockerfile to edit the base image, it will look like

```
FROM wordpress:5.4.0-php7.2-fpm-alpine
COPY ./php.ini /etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini
```

the *./php.ini* is your modified version and the path is the destination.

Bothe above method are persistent and can be applied in build time and start time. But what about runtime, can change modification without restart the container?

Sure you can, you can invoke the *docker cp* command:

```
docker cp ./php.ini container_name:/etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini
```

but the change are not persistent, NOTE: above command can be executed bidirectionally (put in container and take from the container)

To persist the modification you done there is another way I'm aware:

Commit the container modification, more info [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/)

```
docker commit [OPTIONS] CONTAINER [REPOSITORY[:TAG]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't access the php.ini in your docker container, try adding this line just on top of your script where you need it :

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Paris');
```

Comment: Please edit your answer and tell which file exactly he needs to edit.